# String replacement for formatting a name in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column called `names` that has inputs like the following:

```
`name`  
Aaron, James
Aberer, Leo
A.J.
A., Narayana Rao
Abbot Jr., Greg
```

I want to change the formatting such that the first name will come first, this is how it needs to be:

```
`name`
James Aaron
Leo Aberer
A.J.
Narayana Rao A.
Greg Abbot Jr.
```

How would I do this directly in mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN INSTR(name, ',') > 0 
        THEN TRIM(CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', -1), ' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', 1))) 
    ELSE name END AS name_formatted
FROM tbl
```

---

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab9bc/5/0)

Comment: @David542, See updated answer. I've wrapped the string in a `TRIM()` function. See if that works better.

Answer (score 1):

If you can rely on the formatting in MySQL to always have exactly one comma in it, then you can use relatively simple MySQL functions.

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', -1), ' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',' 1))
FROM names
```

But, your input also has one name that has no comma at all.  In this case you need to check if it has a comma first.  If you can rely on your input on always having either zero or one comma, you can use the following.

```
SELECT IF(
  LOCATE(name, ','),
  CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', -1), ' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',' 1)),
  name
) FROM names
```